# HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 early system initialization hangs on 90%

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware

just unboxed a brand new HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 Server.
I can reach the iLO webinterface but the Server hangs on the early system initialization on 90 % with the status code 0114.

I did not find any useful Information on the hp website.

Do you know what the status code mean?

Regards,
Marcel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is an incompatible DIMM module even though the memory module is sold from Kingston as HP compatible.

You can find at the [HP SmartMemory Overview](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14225_div/14225_div.html) a list of compatible DIMMs

Answer (score 2):

You should [check your KVM switch and/or keyboard and monitor.](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)

Move the system to another location... just in case it's an issue with the devices you've connected to it. It seems basic, but it's a fair thing to try.

Comment: Thx for the hint and link but the Server was located on my desk with direct attached keyboard an mouse.

Answer (score 0):

It's brand new.  It's under warranty.  Call HP!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to remove any CD/DVD in the tray and unplug any USB device you might have booted from.