# installing non-hp RAM in hp proliant ml310e G8

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

i bought the hp proliant ml310e G8 with 8GB of crucial RAM. but when i plug it in the system initialization hangs on 90%. i read in another post ([HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 early system initialization hangs on 90%](https://serverfault.com/questions/510011/hp-proliant-ml310e-gen8-early-system-initialization-hangs-on-90)) that you cant install non-hp memory. but is there really no way to this? isnt it possible to skip the initialization?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what Crucial RAM you installed? You can use non-HP RAM, but it has to be the right RAM.

Comment: Crucial DDR3-1600 8GB 1.5v (non-ecc && non-buffered)

Answer (score 5):

You have non-ECC non-buffered memory. This server is designed for ECC Non-buffered memory (UDIMM = Unbuffered DIMM).

So in short - you have wrong memory type. You need ECC UDIMM. Cruical is confirmed to work according to their web site.

Comment: The guarantee only applies if he put in the server when he searched for memory at their web site. It sounds like he didn't, and just went in and bought stuff randomly.

Answer (score 1):

What is the model of the processor?

FYI, Intel Celeron G540, G1610, G1620, G860 and G2020 processors does not support 1600MHz memory while E3-1220Lv2, E3-1220v2, E3-1230v2, E3-1240v2, E3-1270v2, E3-
1280v2, i3-3240, i3-3220 processors supports upto 1600MHz. So check what processor you have and if it supports 1600MHz memory?

Try running memtest86 or install a single module in the first slot of memory channel 1 and check if you face any issue with a particular module, if yes then replace it.