# ProLiant ML310e GEN 8

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I have a ProLiant ML310e GEN 8 that always shows `early system initialization` on startup, and never gets past 90%.  It also has the status code `0114` down in the bottom right hand corner.

Steps I have taken so far:

- I have checked to see if the RAM is approved by HP (it is)
- There are no CD or Flash drive in the sever
- I am not using a KVM and I have tried to boot up without a keyboard, mouse or monitor.
- It is no longer under warranty
- I have tried to boot it with just one RAM stick

I dont know what OS is/was on it and would love to reset the whole thing but i can't even get that far.

Comment: You can find [HP SmartMemory Overview](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetHTML.aspx?docname=c04111535) a compatible DIMMs. and comment link. http://serverfault.com/questions/510011/hp-proliant-ml310e-gen8-early-system-initialization-hangs-on-90

Answer (score 5):

I'm just going to refer you to the [ProLiant hardware troubleshooting flowchart listed here](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen/466340#466340).

> I dont know what OS is/was on it and would love to reset the whole
>   thing but i can't even get that far...

That's concerning. Where did this server come from? Was it a known-good functioning system at some point?

Even beyond that, HP ProLiant Gen8 equipment is under a 3-year manufacturer warranty. It was introduced in September 2012, so your system is **ABSOLUTELY** still under manufacturer support, and you're free to call HP for phone support and parts replacements.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that 0114 relates to the Memory DIMMs. If nothing has changed, I suggest you begin troubleshooting as a bad memory issue.

If you have recently changed memory DIMMs please test without them.

Answer (score -1):

May be performing Memory validation as @Noobixide suggests.  Try booting with a smaller memory footprint, but keep in mind there are strict memory population rules you need to adhere to.

Also there is a bank of jumper switches on your system board (yes those still exist).  Setting Switch 6 on switch bank SW1 will clear NVRAM and reset your system configuration.  Look on the inside of your case cover (hood label) for confirmation on the location of SW1 and the functions.  This is kind of a Hail Mary last ditch effort, but it can be known to clear some bad config data.