# HP ProLiant DL320 G5 No Video Output, No Error LEDs, Swapped Motherboard, Same Issue

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I have a HP ProLiant DL320 G5 Server that we have swapped out the motherboard with a working one, tried narrowing down removing different memory sticks, swapped out the onboard battery.  I have a power supply tester that does not show a fault on the power supply.  The fans kick on, no beep codes, no error LEDs turn on (or beep codes) with either the original or replacement motherboards.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you have a bad CPU or Power module?  If you have a dual CPU setup, you could pull one set and try each one individually..

Answer (score 2):

Your [Proliant DL320 G5](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=12572) is fairly old and a very low-end system. Repair may not be worth it, given the options available now. But I'm assuming you're out of support and trying to self-repair.

This is a single power supply and single CPU socket server. That makes it easy to troubleshoot. I'd guess power supply, motherboard or CPU...

Your best indicator is the ILO2 log and the server's IML log. Have you looked into those yet?

[image]

I'd suggest following the troubleshooting steps outlined in the [**HP ProLiant Servers Troubleshooting Guide**](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00300504/c00300504.pdf).

There are flowcharts which will help you narrow your issue down in a methodical fashion.

Also see: [HP ProLiant DL360 G7 hangs at "Power and Thermal Calibration" screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue with a newer DL385G7, but exact same symptoms.

In my case, the RAM was installed in the wrong *slots*. There was nothing wrong with the RAM itself, the memory slots on the motherboard need to be populated in a particular order. Double check that.

Comment: Luckily, the server in question is old enough that there are only *four* DIMM slots. There aren't any special DIMM population guidelines.

Comment: Ah well, there goes my only suggestion. Sorry.