# dell r710 hangs at bios screen

Tags: dell-poweredge, bios

We have a used dell r710 system that will boot randomly , about 30% of the time. The rest of the time (warm boot or cold boot), the system hangs at the dell bios screen, with the white progress bar about 20% across from the left.

We tried swapping the ram out to try and isolate a bad dimm, that didn't seem to have any affect. Also tried moving the nvram jumpers to see if that might be it, no luck there either.

Wondering if there's anything else we can check or this may just be a bad system board?

Weird thing is, sometimes it will randomly boot.

Answer (score 1):

Check your KVM. Remove the USB keyboard and monitor connections and see if it makes a difference.

And see: [HP ProLiant DL360 G7 hangs at "Power and Thermal Calibration" screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)

Comment: Thanks, tried swapping both the monitor and vga cable, as well as booting without keyb or mouse attached, still hangs. Leaning towards getting a system board replacement at this point.

Comment: Call support :)

Comment: :), yeah this is an ebay server. All good though, turns out the raid battery was causing this. Replaced raid battery with one from a different system, all fixed, no more hangs.