# iLO 2 remote console NO VIDEO?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

my HP ProLiant DL380 G6 server is running fine but iLO does not show any image "no video when"

- iLO firmware has been upgraded to latest version --> 2.25 04/14/2014
- I am using internet explorer 11 to access the service.
- Integrated Remote Console shows grey screen and nothing changes when I ctrl+alt+delete.
- Integrated Remote Console Fullscreen shows "Unable to find a match for 800x600".
- Java based Remote Console shows "no video".
- Problem persist during boot process.
- My computer is on the same network as the server (no firewall involved)
- There is no issue on my computer as I can connect to iLO and open video on other server on the same network on other servers.

**NOTE: **This server is a Hyper-V (don't know if this is relevant)
**NOTE 2: ** The server is running fine as I can RDP and work on it

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

thanks

Comment: What specific boot problems are you having? And what happened right before you wrote this question?

Comment: Hi @ewwhite the issue I am having is with iLO not showing video. The server is running fine

Comment: This is because you upgraded the iLo, but didn't clear your browser cache; you can't use remote-console 1.6 on iLo bios 2.25

Answer (score 3):

This happens when there is a pcie graphic card installed in the server. In that case the bios automatically sets it up as primary display but ILO has no idea how to talk to it (it knows intimate HP parts but no third party components).

I have not dig further to find the bug listed on hp site but for me after entering bios and making the onboard video card as primary, ILO video connection was restored.

Answer (score 2):

If the Integrated Remote Console doesn't work, please try using the Java-based console.

This will help rule out other issues. Also, please verify that this isn't a local problem by accessing the ILO from *another* computer.

The fact that the system is functional and running without issue points to a potential problem with your browser/computer. It should be easy to verify this. [Don't let something small stand in the way of the troubleshooting process](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen).

- Did this ever work? If so, when did it stop working?
- Where is your computer in relation to the ILO in the networking topology?
- Are there firewalls in the way?
- Are the necessary ILO ports open (*you need TCP ports 443 and 23 at a minimum*)?
- Can you confirm that this is a problem from another computer?

[image]

Comment: Hi @ewwhite it is not a local problem as I can open remote console iLO on other servers in the same network as the one I am having issues... java based console says "no video"

Comment: @ManuelSopenaBallesteros See the troubleshooting steps above.

Comment: Port 23? Are you serious?!

Comment: Port 23 is the video port. No text.

Comment: I see no evidence that the Windows HPLOCONS.exe that runs on Gen8 uses either port 23 or 443. It listens on two TCP v4 ports at around 64500 when displaying video.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser cache is loading an old version of the remote console (it's not getting the new update you just installed, because the old one is still in your cache and browser)

Close everything, clear browser caches etc, and re-try.

Answer (score 0):

The Onboard Video should be set to primary. Had the same issue and worked perfectly by setting this in the Bios