# SuperMicro server won't boot after power cycle

Tags: boot, bios

We power cycled one of our SuperMicro machines and it does not boot anymore.
It seems it won't even get to the BIOS loading stage and peripherals (VGA monitor, USB cable) are not detected. All indicators on the chassis itself seem fine (namely the power supply, CPU overheating and even network connection). The LEDs for the PSUs are also green.

We tried removing the disks and booting from a Centos disk but no luck.

To me this seems like a mobo/BIOS issue, but we are completely stuck at the moment, so any suggestions on how to find / fix the issue would come in handy.

Comment: Any reason for downvote other than you are generally having a bad day?

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote button says, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." So presumably that's the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Do you get a POST signal/beep code on boot? Modern motherboards often have a small LCD to display the code. Documentation for the motherboard should list the possible codes.

- If no -> time to start replacing hardware (typically the motherboard is broken or not powered correctly)
- If yes, and it is bad -> Debug from there, depending on the code
- If yes, and it is clear -> Doublecheck the video subsystem

Answer (score 3):

***Call Supermicro support!***

Oh wait... do they provide this type of support? NOPE.

So troubleshoot by breaking things down into pieces. Do you have a KVM in the chain? If so, remove it ([here's why](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen/466340#466340)).

Try to start the system with minimal components. One or two DIMMs and one CPU.

See if it posts.

If it does, add components and keep trying.

If it doesn't... well... You have a larger issue.

Comment: A little bitter, are we?  <grin>  IMAO, *every* hardware vendor sucks, and if you don't have your own pile of on-site spares (regardless of the warranty you bought), you're going to be in for a bad time.