# HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 : does not detect USB keyboard/Mouse after legacy BIOS boot up

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, usb, keyboard-video-mouse

I have a HP proliant DL380 gen 9 which was working just fine, but after a reboot both the USB keyboard and mouse are no longer detected after the legacy BIOS startup.

I tried to use them directly connected to the server, and to go through the iLO card, but it does not respond.

To me, I have to proceed to a factory reset, but maybe there is another way ?

Comment: Are you using a [KVM switch](http://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen/466340#466340)? What type of troubleshooting have you tried... For instance, have you tried a different keyboard and/or mouse?

Comment: Yes I am using a KVM, it worked fine until now, I will remove it from the equation.

Comment: Which USB slots are in use?  Sometimes front/back can make a difference, though normally only when flashing BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes KVMs can be problematic on HP servers... Especially *cheap* KVM switches. Please check this post and follow the troubleshooting decision matrix:

[HP ProLiant DL360 G7 hangs at "Power and Thermal Calibration" screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen/466340#466340)

Comment: Once the KVM gone, the keyboard worked. Thx !