# HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 USB keyboard and mouse not working on Windows 2008 install

Tags: windows-server-2008, hp, hp-proliant, usb

I am trying to install Windows Server 2008 32bit on a HP ProLiant D380 G9 Server and after legacy boot, at the language select page I don't have mouse and keyboard available. Switched between several mice and keyboards, none of them working.
Since I don't have keyboard available, I cannot continue the installation.
I don't use a KVM and nothing else is attached to USB ports.

Comment: Do you get numlock lights?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using the ILO if possible. I'm glad you don't [have a KVM in the mix](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen/466340#466340).

But are you CERTAIN that the keyboard doesn't work? I'm sure I've had situations where the mouse didn't work, but I could still navigate the installer interface using the keyboard (tab, space bar and Enter).

Another thing you could try is bootstrapping your Windows installation using the [Intelligent Provisioning utility](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984) (hit `F10`). This may be important because you're installing an ancient 32-bit OS *(why not 2008 R2?)* on equipment that wasn't designed for it. Many of the requisite drivers would be missing if you didn't do an assisted installation.

Comment: And why not 64-bit? Installing a 32-bit anything is just asking for trouble.

Comment: 2008R2 is 64-bit only. So, there would need to be a very special reason for installing onto this platform. These systems are not meant to be used this way.

Comment: Right. If you really _need_ an ancient OS, you install a modern hypervisor, and virtualize it.

Comment: The real reason: the USB driver on 2008 and 2008R2 doesn't work. You can temporary work using the ILO console but run away as soon as you can!!!