# Getting data off of HP Proliant DL380 G5 RAID 5 drives

Tags: raid, hp-proliant

I have an old DL380 G5 with a dead VGA.  I'd like to pull the data from the 3 drives (I assume configured as RAID 5 given the # of drives – it was before my time).  Is there any way to get at that data or is replacing the VGA board the best option?

Comment: Does the VGA matter? I'm not sure I understand the connection between the monitor ports (there are two) and the integrity of the data on the disks. Can you explain what you intend to do?

Comment: I need to be able to see the Windows system to grab the data.  Both VGA are dead – the screen just flickers colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use the front VGA port on the server or perhaps the rear VGA port.
- Try a different monitor or [eliminate the KVM switch](https://serverfault.com/a/466340/13325).
- If neither works, you may be able to use the ILO2 port on the server.
- If this is a server running Windows, you may have RDP enabled at the OS level. Use that.
- You can move the data to a similar server as well.

Comment: No KVM in place.  Tried both VGA ports.  Will check ILO.  RDP is tough because I believe it was configured statically on a network that I don't have credentials for any more and the A/D server that managed it is long gone.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use the HP On-board Management to check the current RAID configuration on your server. Also you can use the ILO to get remote access to your server.
2. If you want to move the data from the entire RAID disk, you can use many softwares (backup software), P2V or xcopy / robocopy (if just data files) to a different location.
3. If you have a VGA issue (Mainboard VGA), I suggest you to buy an VGA card (Probably PCIe, you need to check the slots on your server). This will be more cheap and easy for you.

Comment: 1. Will try.  Thanks.  3. Was afraid of that.