# HP Proliant DL385 G6 - won't Post

Tags: hp

I have a HP Proliant DL385 G6 that is unable to post. Once the power button is pressed the fans begin to spin up but no video is displayed. The system health monitor turns green.

I have tried:
Replacing/Reseating the PSU's 
Resetting using the System Maintenance Switches

I am totally new at this and would love some help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The documentation is your friend.

Comment: these models are quite long to display the post (like 3/4 minutes), how long did you wait ?

Comment: I waited a good ten minutes

Answer (score 1):

Please troubleshoot according to the following:

See: [HP ProLiant DL360 G7 hangs at "Power and Thermal Calibration" screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)

[image]

Comment: +1, good diag chart

Comment: I have done all the checks up to the port 85 codes, where is a good reference to what those mean?

Comment: Break the server down to minimal configuration. One CPU and one DIMM.