# HP ProLiant DL360P G8 stuck on post

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

My HP ProLiant DL360P G8 started acting wierd after I started it up for the first time since last year. When it turns on it enters POST but gets stuck on "Memory and QPI Initialization Start" with status code 0168 and percentage 20%. It does not progress any futher after this point.

I've tried to clear CMOS and NVRAM via both removing CMOS battery, PSU and toggling maintenance switch #6, updating BIOS, reseated/removed and even tested without memory. I've also tried to use the redundant ROM via switches #1, #5, #6 with no success, nothing on screen only beeps. If I try to switch ROM via ILO 4 nothing happens. I've yet to find something simular to my problem online, any advise?

[Image of POST screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7AzL.png)

Specs:

- 1 Intel Xeon E5-2620
- 2x HP 16GB RDIMM 647653-081 in slot 1 and 12
- 2x HP 4GB RDIMM 647647-071 in slot 4 and 9
  Nothing else attached except for built in raid card and HP NIC

Answer (score 3):

Please check your keyboard, mouse and video situation.

Are you using a KVM?

[HP ProLiant DL360 G7 hangs at "Power and Thermal Calibration" screen](https://serverfault.com/q/465883/13325)

Comment: I've used both ILO4 and my KVM. I've currently got the server on a bench hooked up via VGA to a normal monitor but the problem persists. It does not seem to be a video problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing just the two 16GB RDIMMs in slots 12A and 9B and see if the server boots up without issues. Leave the two 4GB RDIMMs out of the server for the test. If it has the same issue, swap the two 4GB RDIMMs with the 16GB RDIMMs. This will rule out if it's a bad memory stick.

Comment: Both configurations tested and failed. Still stuck on the screen. The same screen appears whilst there is no memory installed even. Shouldn't it spit out an error on the screen that no memory is installed?

Comment: Sounds like it may be a system board issue. Unfortunately, it might be time to open a call to HP support.